# Am I doing something wrong with my simple factorial calculator C++ program?

Tags: c++

Half an hour ago, I made a simple factorial calculator that takes non-zero integers as inputs. After testing it for some values, I noticed that it only work properly until 12!.

I haven't been programming for some months now, and still am a beginner to be honest. I decided to use recursion so I could get back in to "programming mode" faster (my preference).

I checked and modified it for almost an hour now. I don't really know what is wrong with my algorithm.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int factorial(int);

int main()
{
    int usrInput = 0;   //initialize input variable
    cout << "Please input the factorial you want to calculate: ";
    cin >> usrInput;
    while(usrInput < 1)
    {
        cout << "Please input a valid number: ";
        cin >> usrInput;
    } //end while
    cout << "\nAnswer: " << factorial(usrInput) << '\n';
    return 0;
}

int factorial(int n)
{
    int product = n;
    if(n < 2)
        product = 1;
    else
    {
        product *= factorial(n-1);
    cout << "\n" << product; //debugging line
    } //end if else
    return product;
}
```

Comment: Questions you should be asking yourself: how big is `13!`? how many bits do my `int`s have? What's the max value they can represent?

Comment: You get integer overflow. What is the largest factorial you want to calculate?

Comment: @Mat I see. Is this the "think like a computer" concept?

Comment: @MichałSzczygieł I'm guessing any factorial. My goal for this program is to start flexing my programming muscles little by little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You exceed limits of int. 13! = 6227020800, int only covers -2147483648 .. 2147483647. Use bigger type (eg. __int64), double (but you'll lose precision) or implement (or use) big number library.

Comment: I see. Does C++ have a standard library for numbers larger than the double's limit?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such standard library, you'll have to find one or write your own (what is quite easy for addition, subtraction and multiplication)